# What is the default unit for maxDistance in Mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It's not really clear what should be the unit for `$maxDistance` in mongodb geospatial queries.

Here is my code

```
 return await User.find({
                location: {
                    $near: {
                        $maxDistance: maxDistance, //Is this in Meters or KM?
                        $geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
                        }
                    }
                },
```

I would love my `$maxDistance` to always be in Meters. What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search operator `$near` [uses meters in `$maxDistance` and `minDistance`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#mongodb-query-op.-near).

> ```
>    $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
>    $minDistance: <distance in meters>
> ```